# Cannot get nohup, open_init_pty and sudo to work together

Tags: linux, bash, sudo, nohup

I'm struggling to combine nohup, open_init_pty and sudo in a one-liner. Something like this:

```
nohup open_init_pty sudo bash -c "command1;command2"
```

My requirements are a little strange:

- Use nohup so parent shell can exit cleanly
- open_init_pty as actually inside a remote SSH via PHP which requires this
- sudo to run privileged commands
- Run multiple commands - hence the bash -c line

I've tried to narrow down the problem using different combinations:

```
# works OK, output in nohup.out
nohup sudo bash -c "echo hello"

# works OK, hello output to console
open_init_pty sudo bash -c "echo hello"

# doesn't work
nohup open_init_pty sudo bash -c "echo hello"
```

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: Erm... eh.  I removed the bounty as I was going to migrate to [unix.se].  But it is *tentatively* on topic here.  So if you want to put the bounty back on go ahead.  Otherwise, @reply and I'll migrate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about doing it without nohup?  You can start a subshell like this:

```
(open_init_pty sudo bash -c "echo hello")
```

I sometimes do this with a `&` on the end, but your examples didn't run in the background.  Anyway, this may accomplish your goal of not having the job terminate if the parent shell exits.